# HAProxy URLs LoadBalancing

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, high-availability

I have this setup

1. HAProxy Server
2. Two Nginx web servers

I need to redirect user according to the URLs
But the URLs is variable not static URLs (domainname/variablename)
I used (balance url_param id) but it isn’t work each user go to different server
I need to force user that has the same url go to the same backend server

This is my haproxy configuration

```
frontend haproxynode
bind *:80
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/domainname.pem
http-request redirect scheme https unless { ssl_fc }
mode http
default_backend backendnodes

backend backendnodes
mode http
balance url_param id
option httpchk
hash-type consistent
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
server node1 x.x.x.x:4444 check ssl verify none
server node2 x.x.x.x:4444 check ssl verify none
```

Comment: which version of HAProxy do you use? When you remove `hash-type consistent` does it change anything?

Comment: At first i used haproxy v1.8 after that i used the latest 2.2 it's the same problem in the 2 versions. When i remove hash-type consistent no thing changes.

Comment: the `url_param` is used for query string. Is the id in the query string `url?id=...`? Please can you check the doc for the [balance](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#4-balance) directive.